# "Das Haar" oder "die Haare" als Kopfbehaarung

Tags: noun, grammatical-number

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [When should one use singular form of “hair”, when plural?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3015/when-should-one-use-singular-form-of-hair-when-plural)

Nennt man die Kopfbehaarung "das Haar" oder "die Haare"?

> Ich trage mein Haar / meine Haare lang.
>
> Das Haar / die Haare schneiden
>
> Tolles Haar! / Tolle Haare!

Comment: Scalp is the tissue on top of your head that has many hairs attached to it. I think *die Haare* makes more sense.

Comment: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3015/when-should-one-use-singular-form-of-hair-when-plural (I remember my -1 answers forever) ;) Hallo Tim!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beides wird benutzt.

Tragen kann man *das Haar* und *die Haare* lang.

Geschnitten werden aber *die Haare*. Das Haar schneiden zu lassen wäre zumindest sehr ungewöhnlich, obwohl man beim Pferd das Haar striegeln kann, und singen: *Come on, Babe, schüttel Dein Haar für mich!*

*Tolles Haar* kann man sagen, wenn man die Haarbeschaffenheit meint. Der Frisur würde man mit *Tolle Haare!* schmeicheln.

Answer (score 3):

Neben der Beschreibung von user unknown (+1), scheint "das Haar" im poetischen Kontext recht verbreitet zu sein. Meine kleine Tochter, ihres Zeichens glühende Anhängerin von Prinzessinen und Elfen, spricht in der entsprechenden Stimmung davon "ihr Haar" zu kämmen, obwohl sie im Alltagsgebrauch durchaus einfach "die Haare" kämmt.